# Can´t update a Model entity with several ICollection properties MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, properties, model, updatemodel, icollection

Here is my problem,

I have the next Model in Componet.cs (My real component has ten more Icollections but as I think the problem should be the same with 1 ICollection or with 10 I´m not writting them down).

```
public partial class Component
{
    public Component()
    {
        this.BrandOwner = new HashSet<BrandOwner>();
        this.Description = new HashSet<Description>();
    }

    public int GestCompID { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BaseGestCompID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BaseCompID { get; set; }
    public string DefName { get; set; }
    public string ProductRef { get; set; }

    public virtual country country { get; set; }
    public virtual language language { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BrandOwner> BrandOwner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Description> Description { get; set; }
```

In my application I can edit that component in order to add, delete or edit any of its attributtes. I can add several BrandOwners or Descriptions depending the Country or the language.
When I select one of those components to Edit I load the Component in a Session variable, and do all the actions over that Session variable.

When I´m finish editing the item I have two buttoms, Accept and Cancel.
If I cancel all the changes made in the Session variable are discharged.

The problem comes when I push the Accept button to update the selected item. I can´t find the way to

Here is my Accept method:

```
    public ActionResult AcceptChanges()
    {
        try
        {
            Component component = (Component)Session["component"];
            GIEntities.Current.Component.Attach(component);
            GIEntities.Current.SaveChanges();
            Session["component"] = null;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", new { Message = "correct" });
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            String error = ex.ToString();
            Component component = (Component)Session["component"];
            return RedirectToAction("EditComponent", new { id = componente.ID });
        }
    }
```

I have tried attaching, adding and setting the status to Modified, but it won´t work.
I have also tried detaching de component and attaching it again.
Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much and thanks in advance.

Sorry my bad english.